# Error Adding Event to Google Calendar

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to write an event to the Google Calendar of the User that is logged into my application. I have already requested permissions for: GET_ACCOUNTS, WRITE_CALENDAR, and READ_CALENDAR. I am unsure how to fix the error I am receiving. Thank you in advance!

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=5, result=-1, data=Intent {  launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has extras) }} to activity {socialhour.socialhour/socialhour.socialhour.frontend_activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4472)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
                                                                       at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:48)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.auth.zze.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:269)
                                                                       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:294)
                                                                       at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
                                                                       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
                                                                       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
                                                                       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
                                                                       at socialhour.socialhour.frontend_activity.addEventToCalendar(frontend_activity.java:376)
                                                                       at socialhour.socialhour.frontend_activity.parseNewEventData(frontend_activity.java:216)
                                                                       at socialhour.socialhour.frontend_activity.onActivityResult(frontend_activity.java:181)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7256)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4468)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```